# refresh div based on link click with data pulled from php file

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have an image scroller with a selection of images in it. These images are pulled out of the database.  Above the scroller are a list of folders.

When the user click a new folder I want the list of images to update without refreshing the page.  I have had a go at making this with ajax but its confusing me a little and is not working at all.  Here is what i have got so far

first the default html/php page

the images that are there now a just for test.  these will be the default images in no folder when the query is written

**About.php**
the folders list

```
   <div id="folders">
    <ul id="foldername">

        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="getImages()">test0</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="getImages(1)">test1</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="getImages(2)">test2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

then the scroller

```
   <div id="scrolimg">
    <img name="" src="" width="150" height="150" alt="" class="singlscrolimg" />

  </div>
```

**getImage.php**

```
      include('../Connections/dbcon.php');
   mysql_select_db($database_dbcon, $dbcon);
   $query_rs_image = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE imgfolder='".$_GET['id']."' AND     status='1'";
   $rs_image = mysql_query($query_rs_image, $dbcon) or die(mysql_error());
   $row_rs_image = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_image);
   $totalRows_rs_image = mysql_num_rows($rs_image);

 do { ?>

 <img name="<?php echo $row_rs_image['imgname']; ?>" src="/images/uploads/<?php echo $row_rs_image['smfile']; ?>"  alt="<?php echo $row_rs_image['imgname']; ?>" />
  <?php } while ($row_rs_image = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_image)); ?>
```

and at the top of about.php

```
   <script>

   function getImages(id)
    {
     $.ajax({

      type: "GET",
      url: 'getImage.php',
      data: "id=" + id, 
      success: function(data) {

      $('#scrolimg').html(data);
     }

     });

  }
  </script>
```

Comment: Placing a `GET` variable straight into a `mysql_*` query seems like a good idea, and probably won't cause you any problems with injection at all?

Comment: @adeneo that should not be a problem.   these files are already in an admin area which only one user has access to

Comment: assume you are able to get new images loaded? Issue would be what methods does scroller support to destroy and reinitialize? Try just initializing it after new images loaded and see what happens

Comment: @charlietfl ok I have relised the path was wrong to the getImage file and now it works perfectly.  One question though.  As this is my first ajax request.  Is this the correct way to do what I want as adeneo above seems to think it is dangerous.

Comment: the AJAX concept is fine... he's just pointing out that mysql queries should be sanitized to avoid database corruption. As it stands right now would be easy to delete your whole database with a simple input in form